# How to fetch the latest posts in Laravel if I paginate the results?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

So I have this in `PagesController`:

[image: PagesController]

And I have this in my View:

[image: View Code Example]

Everything works well on the first page, but when I switch to the second page, it displays the latest posts only from the second page. I want to be able to display the same latest posts through all the pages.

Comment: if you want to display the latest posts in all pages, why use `paginate()`?

Comment: Please post your actual code here, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you would need to pass latest `PostS` separately.

```
public function getIndex()
{
    // other codes...
    $builder = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    $latest = $builder->take(5)->get();
    $posts = $builder->paginate(5);

    return view('pages.welcome', compact('latest', 'posts', 'categories'));
}
```